# How to solve $T(n) = 27T(n/9) + n^3$ with substitution method

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I'm trying to bound this recurrence with the substitution method. My guess is $O(n^3)$. These are some steps:
$$T(n) \leq cn^3 \\ T(n) \leq 27cn^3+n^3$$
How can I continue?

Comment: Do you realise that $\frac{27n}{9} = 3n$?

Comment: This question makes no sense, the result will be a negative number. Since the RHS has $T(3n)$ and $3n>n$, you will need to rearrange in order to substitute correctly. After the rearranging it will be clear why the result is negative.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the recurrence relation you are trying to solve is:
$$T(n) = 27T(n /9) + n^3$$

Using the substitution method, you can prove that for any $k \leqslant \log_3 n$:
$$T(n) = 3^{3k}T\left(\frac{n}{3^{2k}}\right) + n^3\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{27^i}$$

For $k = \log_3n$, we get $T(n) \leqslant n^3T(1) + n^3\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{27^i}=n^3(T(1) + \frac{27}{26})$.

Since clearly $T(n) \geqslant n^3$, we conclude that $T(n) = \Theta(n^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have T(3n) = T(n) - n^3.

If T(1) = c, then T(3) = c-1, T(9) = c - 28, T(27)=c-757 etc.